# JavaCV/OpenCV error in Win7

Tags: netbeans, opencv, javacv

64 bit,JDK 1.7,OpenCV 2.40,New version of JavaCV for the code

```
package test; 

 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core; 
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui; 
 import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame; 

        public class Test{ 
        public static void main(String args) { 
        final IplImage image = cvLoadImage("img1.png");
        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Demo");
        canvas.showImage(image);
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  } 
}
```

I am getting the following error for the above code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\BBPATIL\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp173171889406337\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:418)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
    at sdmcetd.main(sdmcetd.java:11)
Java Result: 1
```

Please anybody help me as soon as possible..!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Set your environment variables such as paths, classpaths to openCV directories.
If the problem exist, download javacv-0.1.jar from internet and make it as your library.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have set path variable properly.
- Bitness if javacv and opencv should be same

You can find detailed instruction at link below.

http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html